# Getting user's Office 365 email when writing a MS Word Add-In

Tags: c#, ms-word, office365

I have a problem finding a way to get the email of an user that is logged into Office 365 and opens MS Word through it. Any help is welcome, I'm using VS2017 and C#. Any help is welcome.

// I mean the email *address* you log in with to access your Office software.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean the user's *email address*, or the contents of their Outlook email account (like from their Inbox)? It's important when asking a question here that you **be specific** about what you're asking if you expect help from us.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I made it clear that it's the Office login email, not the Outlook one. The one you log in with to access Office.

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: No, and your edit makes it no more clear. You don't log in with an email, you log in with an email address (account). As I said, **be specific**.

Comment: I might've assumed it's obvious that what you use to log in is an email address and not the email itself, sorry. I mean the address, of course. That's what I'm trying to get.

Comment: Does this help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-currentwebuser-method-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That works just fine, June7. I had some problems finding the C# API. I also found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.useraddress.aspx) in case you're interested.

Comment: I strongly suggest you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help], particulary [ask], before your next post here. This site is for **specific questions**, not *Here's a vague idea of what I'm looking for; I assume you can fill in the blanks or figure things out yourself* posts.

Comment: You're right, I'm very sorry for assuming things and that's something I won't do again. I don't see why you're sending me back to the tour though, as I clearly showed intentions of trying to make this thread as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do with the javascript api Word as of now. (in outlook you can), however, you can use the Microsoft Graph and get the user's profile by invoking the REST  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/